# Domain Controller Upgrade 2016 to 2022

Tags: windows-server-2016, domain-controller, upgrade, windows-server-2022

There are 3 Domain Controllers in my environment, all running Windows Server 2016 Standard:

1. Primary DC : On-prem (FSMO role)
2. Secondary DC : On-prem
3. Tertiary DC : Cloud

I want to upgrade The domain environment to Windows Server 2022. I have tried to direct upgrade from mounted ISO. This didn't work and returned BSOD errors "SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED".

[image]

I have tried by removing all third party applications, change CPU count and run memory diagnostics but this did not resolve the problems.

I decided to install another DC and replace the secondary domain controller. But I need to keep it same as secondary domain controller IP and Hostname. What is best practice achieve this?

Comment: Install new, move FSMO and your done, why trying a useless inplace upgrade for a DC?

Comment: `They need to keep it same as secondary domain controller IP and Hostname.What is best practice achieve this?` Demote second DC, format hard drive, install Windows, promote to DC using the same name and IP address.

Comment: They same hostname and ip can be tricky. Why do they need to keep the same ip and hostname? And can you still logon to that dc that has issues?

Comment: any idea what are the steps to follow clean all the record of old domaincontroller records. or just domain controller from AD?

Comment: Just demote it, that action should clean everything up. But, before doing any stuff like DC promotion/demotion, check consistency with at least `repadmin /replsummary`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have still access to that failed domain controller, you can use this powershell script to demote it

```
# Import the ADDSDeployment module
Import-Module ADDSDeployment

# Demote the server
Uninstall-ADDSDomainController -DemoteOperationMasterRole:$true -RemoveDnsDelegation:$true -Force:$true

# Run the following command after the reboot to remove the Active Directory Sites and Services
Uninstall-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools
```

Then reboot and remove it from sites and services.
https://lazyadmin.nl/it/demote-domain-controller/

Then wait a half hour so to make sure everything is replicated.
Then turn off the dc that you just have demoted, and make sure there are no dns records left for that machine. Also run `dcdiag /v` to make sure your domain is still healthy.

Then spin up a new machine, maybe good to sysprep it, assign it the proper ip, and set the primary dc as primary dns server in the IP configuration. Then change the name and reboot and then after the reboot start the dcpromo.